# How to determine the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[x^2\mid y]$

Tags: probability

If $[x,y]^{T}$ is a two dimensional Gaussian random variable with zero mean and 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[x,y]^{T}[x,y]=\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_x^2 & r_{xy}\\
  r_{yx}& \sigma_y^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
my question is how to determine the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[x^2\mid y]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the joint pdf:
$$
   f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2-r_{XY}^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2-r_{XY}^2} \left( \sigma_Y^2 x^2 + \sigma_X^2 y^2 -2 r_{XY} x y \right) \right)
$$
The conditional pdf is, by definition:
$$
   f_{X|Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
$$
where $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal pdf:
$$
   f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_Y} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{y^2}{\sigma_Y^2} \right)
$$
Use it to find the expectation:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(X^2 \mid Y=y\right) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_{X\mid Y}\left(x\mid y\right) \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Thank you! I have finished it.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that conditional distribution of normal random variables is a normal random variable $X \mid Y=y \sim \mathcal{N} (y\rho\sigma_{x}/\sigma_{y},\sigma_{x}(\sqrt {1-\rho^2})$

and $\sigma^2_{X \mid Y}=E[X^2 \mid Y=y]-\mu^2_{X \mid Y}$

Substitute and done!